# Apple ID Authentication through Angular 9/10

Tags: angular, authentication

I have implemented google and FB Authentication by using angularx-social-login. But I couldn't find any dependency or source to implement apple ID authentication.
Is there any way to do that? Please provide the information.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Unlike google and facebook, apple sign-in is not supported by `angularx-social-login`. It has to be done by other library such as `ngx-apple-signin`, there a little bit difference between apple and the others because apple sign-in do a post authenticate redirect to your website again which you have to handle.

[Here you can find the package documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-apple-signin)

[Here is a useful example similar to your case](https://dev.to/rrdlpl/sign-in-with-appleid-angular-nestjs-5ejp)